# How to call a python script from a web page

Tags: php, python, python-2.7, web, json-rpc

I'm pretty new to Python and Web applications, so I apologize for possible terms/keywords mix up.

I have a Python script that runs a json-rpc server, exporting some management APIs of a device.
I've written another Python script to implement a CLI control application (using Python's cmd module). Everything is run in an Ubuntu12.04 machine.

Now, I would like to replace the CLI application with a very simple web page (Is it called a web application? Or a web service? Maybe a WSGI? Something else?). The page should present a way to call an API, with arguments set by the user, and possibly display the result.
What's the best way (min learning curve and min development time...) to proceed?

Should I write some PHP code (from searching OS, it seems a popular way to go) and call another Python script from it?
Can I do it entirely with Python (probably yes, but will it be easy?)?

Any hints/directions/suggestions will be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You can run a python script via php, and outputs on browser.

Basically you have to call the python script this way:

```
$command = "python /path/to/python_script.py 2>&1";
$pid = popen( $command,"r");
while( !feof( $pid ) )
{
 echo fread($pid, 256);
 flush();
 ob_flush();
 usleep(100000);
}
pclose($pid);
```

Note: if you run any time.sleep() in you python code, it will not outputs the results on browser.
For full codes working, [visit How to execute python script from php and show output on browser](http://blog.idealmind.com.br/php/how-to-execute-python-script-from-php-and-show-output-on-browser/)

Comment: Thanks LLingas! I assume the code snip should be put in a PHP page, right? Any recommendations for a tool to generate such a page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript and ajax for this if the API and your page are on the same server. There are few json-rpc library written in javascript, the [list is on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC).

Comment: Thanks jcubic! That would require me to have some knowledge of javascript and/or ajax. Isn't there a framework in Python to do it?

Comment: @DgAn You can create CGI script with a form (html), and in response to a form (in python) you can write code that will use the API the same as your cli script.